# Forward ssh-agent socket from login node to worker in slurm

Tags: ssh, slurm

Is there any way to forward my ssh-agent socket to workers using slurm? I want this to protect my private key from being accessed by others.
I can already forward my agent to login node with `ssh -A`.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to ``reverse forward ssh-agent'' from worker node to login node:

```bash
if [[ $(hostname) == login* ]] ;
then
  echo 'Welcome to login node'
  export LOGIN_NODE_NAME=$HOSTNAME
else
  echo 'Welcome to job node'
  ssh -NfL ~/.ssh/$(hostname).sock:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK -o 'StreamLocalBindUnlink=yes' -o 'ExitOnForwardFailure=yes' $LOGIN_NODE_NAME
  export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/$(hostname).sock
  ssh-add -L >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo 'SSH-Agent forwarding success'
fi
```